# is there a way to select only records with ingredient numbers of 3 or more

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, row-number, sequential-number

I have a table of compound ingredients. depending on the product each product may have more than one ingredient number:

| Product | Ingred No |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 2 |
| D | 3 |
| D | 4 |

I only want to select products with 3 or more ingredients so the result would be:

| Product | IngredNo |
| --- | --- |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 2 |
| D | 3 |
| D | 4 |

Hope this makes sense!

i did try `Row_Number partition by product`, but i cannot get it to work.

i tried the following and it works by itself:

```
( SELECT product FROM Ingreds 
       GROUP BY product HAVING COUNT(0) > 3 ) y
        ON y.product = x.product))
```

But when i use it in a where clause :

```
select product,ingredno
from Ingreds
where exists ( SELECT product FROM Ingreds 
       GROUP BY product HAVING COUNT(0) > 3 ) y
        ON y.product = x.product))
```

i still get all the records, not the one with more than 3 ingredients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
INNER JOIN (
( 
   SELECT product 
   FROM Ingreds 
   GROUP BY product 
   HAVING COUNT(0) >= 3 
) g ON g.product = p.product
```